# How to make conditional props in Bootstrap Button Group in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `useState` as below:

```
 const [orderStandard, setOrderStandard] = useState("total");
```

And according to the value of `orderStandard`, I want to give props.

This below code is `ButtonGroup` of BootStrap with ReactJS.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/button-group/#button-toolbar-props

```
   <ButtonGroup
            style={{
              height: 35,
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Button
              id="order-button"
              variant="light"
              style={{ width: 80 }}
              active
              onClick={() => setOrderStandard("total")}
            >
```

above, among props of Button, `active` make button being selected.

So I make it conditional as below.

[image]

However it throws error. Error says: `'...' expected.ts(1005)`

So I make with `...`

```
 <Button
                  id="order-button"
                  variant="light"
                  style={{ width: 80 }}
                  {...(orderStandard == "total" ? active : null)}
                  onClick={() => setOrderStandard("total")}
                >
```

But when I wrote code above, It says `active` props is not defined.

[image]

How can I make it?

Comment: Hy, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
active={orderStandard == "total" ? true : false)}
```

If he scolds `false` you can try with `null` and `undefined`

Comment: Agree with this answer. The way Hyejung wrote it, the code is looking for a variable `active` in local scope instead of passing a boolean property named `active`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `'active' is not defined` because you're trying to use `active` as a variable instead of using it as an attribute of `Button`.

Try this instead

```js
 <Button
  id="order-button"
  variant="light"
  style={{ width: 80 }}
  active={orderStandard == "total"}
  onClick={() => setOrderStandard("total")}
 >
```